# What is the formal negation of the statement "There is much X in Y".

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

What is the formal negation of the statement "There is much X in Y"?

The answer to me is that "It is not the case that there is much X in Y" But I want a more useful negation. Can I say that its negation would be "There is little X in Y or There is no X in Y"? But it's because "There is much X in Y" is very unspecific, some may say that "There is much X in Y" could be true even if there's only one X in Y. So its negation would then be just "There is no X in Y"?

Thank you

Comment: you will get better answers if you try philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: There isn't much X in Y.

Comment: In order to get an answer here, you probably need to be willing to accept some concrete definition of what "much" means. If it means $Y$ has elements that are more than half contained in $X$, for example, then the negation is clear.

Comment: Look into fuzzy logic, this question is basically what it is all about

Comment: I think you can hardly get a formal negation of an informal statement.

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers

Comment: You can see [Generalized Quantifiers](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/) and e.g. Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&pg=PA287) (2011), page 287, for "most of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major source of ambiguity in your statement, taken as is, is that "much" could technically refer to "much in terms of $X$" or "much in terms of $Y$." I.e., when you say there is "much $X$ in $Y$," which set, $X$ or $Y$, does "much" refer to? Even more than that though, "much" could be interpretted as either a relative percentage/measure/cardinality or absolute count/measure/cardinality. You have to decide whether "much" means a high enough relative percentage/measure/cardinality of elements (whether in $X$ or $Y$), i.e. you compare the elements in the intersection to the elements of one of the sets, or an absolute high enough number/cardinality of elements (whether in $X$ or $Y$), i.e. you just look at the elements in the intersection regardless of what $X$ and $Y$ look like. Furthermore, you have to decide what the thresholds are in either case to deserve the title "much."

Comment: Could it be for example that only one X in Y could make the statement "There's much X in Y" true?

Comment: @user1003034742 Sure, if $X$ has just one element and it is in $Y$ and you are using $X$ as your reference for the definition of "much," and you are using percentage of elements to define "much," Then 100 percent of $X$ is in $Y$. Similarly if $Y$ has just one element and that element is in $X$, and you define "much" with respect relatively to $Y.$ Then 100 percent of the elements of $Y$ are in $X$. Either way, this could qualify as "much"

Answer (score 0):

"Much" is an ambiguous measure.  How much is "much"?

But however much is "much", the negation of "There is much X in Y" is "There is not much X in Y".

We *might* further interpret that "not much" would mean "little-or-none".

Comment: Can it be that in some cases "not much" only means "none"?

Comment: @user1003034742  Not typically.  Generally, "not none" is taken to mean "some", which can be "any at all", where as "much" also infers some greatness of quantity.